# How to implement two types of return in a fragment's onCreateView?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to create a registration page where there is return for a button that can be clicked to a login page and then I need to return a binding command for the registration form to the firebase but I cannot use two types of return because onCreateView only allows return to be implemented once. But the button's "return view" and the registration form's "return binding.root" are two different types of returns that cannot be combined.

How can I implement both of these returns at the same time?

Here is the code:

```js
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register_email, container, false)

        view.navigate_to_login_register_email.setOnClickListener { view ->
            requireActivity().run {
                startActivity(Intent(this, LogIn::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }

        return view

        binding = FragmentRegisterEmailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        binding.registerButtonEmail.setOnClickListener {
            validateData()
        }

        return binding.root
```

Comment: Returning two values doesn't make sense. If you are using ViewBinding remove that `view`, it's of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inflating the same layout twice, in two different ways. That's creating two copies, and you're setting one click listener in one layout, and another in the other layout. And your fragment can only use one of them for its `view` - whichever you pass back, it'll be missing a click listener.

If you're using view binding, and you're keeping a reference to the binding object (which you are, and that's how you'd normally do it) then just do this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        // generate your binding class by inflating the layout
        binding = FragmentRegisterEmailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)

        // set your listeners on the views in the layout
        binding.navigateToLoginRegisterEmail.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().run {
                startActivity(Intent(this, LogIn::class.java))
                finish()
            }
        }

        binding.registerButtonEmail.setOnClickListener {
            validateData()
        }

        // return the root of the view hierarchy (i.e. the inflated layout)
        return binding.root
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for helping out. I'm still a newbie

Comment: @Tommy- no worries, you'll get the hang of things! Functions in Kotlin and Java can only return one value. If you need to return more than one thing, you need to put them inside another (single) object like a ``List`` or a ``Pair`` (or a class you define yourself that holds multiple things). But you're implementing a standard function here (``onCreateView``) which has a fixed signature (parameters + return type) so you *have* to return a `View`. Even if you *could* return `Pair(view1, view2)` the code that calls this function wouldn't be written to handle that, because it's expecting a `View`